# hibernate bidirectional association with primary key as foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-one

I'm having a lot of problems with a JPA relationship. I've been searching through the internet and have found lots of cases similar to mine but the proposed solutions are not working for me. Let me show you the java classes mapping the Oracle tables:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CONFIGURATIONS")
public class Configuration implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="EAC_ID")
    private int id;

    @OneToMany
    @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="ACT_EAC_ID", nullable=false)
    private List<Actions> actions;

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="ACTIONS")
public class Actions implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ACT_ID")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ACT_EAC_ID", updatable=false, insertable=false)
    private Configuration configuration;

    @OneToMany
    @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="ECF_ACT_ID", nullable=false)
    private List<Filter> filters;

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="FILTERS")
public class Filter implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private FilterPK id = new FilterPK();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ECF_ACT_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Actions action = null;

    ...
}

@Embeddable
public class FilterPK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="ECF_KEY", nullable=false, length=100)
    private String key;

    @Column(name="ECF_ACT_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int actionId;

}
```

The thing is that when storing a new Configuration into the database, all its associated Actions should be automatically stored, as well as the Filters associated to these Actions.

Currently, the Configuration and its Actions are stored automatically (without the Filters). This is how I have achieved this:

```
public int createConfiguration(Configuration conf) {

    for(Actions act : conf.getActions()) {
        act.setConfiguration(conf);
    }

    em.persist(conf);

    return conf.getId();
}
```

The problem is that when I add the Filter mappings, I always get this exception:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21)         MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit.ame: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."ame": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: ame]  Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:103)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.0.Final-redhat-1]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit:ame] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:930)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:92)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:200)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.access$600(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:57)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:99)
... 4 more
**Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: Filter column: ECF_ACT_ID (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")**
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:682)
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:704)
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:726)
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:479)
at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1284)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1742)
at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:920)
... 9 more
```

Has anybody experienced the same kind of issue? How could I solve this?

Thanks in advance for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add mappedBy to your OneToMany annotations and remove the join columns on the onetomany sides (they are already defined on the manytoone side).

```
public class Configuration
...
@OneToMany(mappedBy="configuration")
private List<Actions> actions;
```

You probably also want to remove the insertable=false, updateble=false

Comment: The relationship between Configuration and Actions is already working properly. The problem is with the Actions - Filter relationship.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Use also the same annotation patern on your actions filters it is the same kind of relationship